# linux virtual comport drivers for AR drone.

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, c, embedded-linux

I have been working on this problem for quite a while now and cannot seem to find the correct driver for Linux to interface with an STM32F407. The Linux runs on an AR drone 2.0. The STM already acts as a virtual Com-port as itself when I connect it to my computer and then I can interact with it. On the AR drone 2.0 it is not listed as a COM-port but it does detect it as a USB device when I attach it. When I telnet it, it gives me this information:

`Bus 001 device 002: ID 0483:5740 SGS Thomson Microelectronics 
Bus 001 device 001: ID 1d6b:0002`

The first one is obviously the one I need to look at and I looked at the vendor ID on this website. http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids

this vendor ID gave me indeed the STM32F407, but I cannot find the Linux driver for this device. I was able to put the STM into a Linux computer and then looked at what driver it used. It was the CDC_AMC driver. I looked it up but now I have the next problem. it needs the virtual COM-Port driver to interact with the STM32. The Drone runs on a busybox Linux version v1.14.0 and I have not enough experience with Linux to know what driver I have to use and where I can find it.

Does it also have something to do with what processor it uses? In that case, the drone has a: ARM Cortex A8 1 GHz 32-bit processor.

Comment: You'll probably have to re-compile the kernel for the AR drone (where does the kernel that runs on this drone come from?) and enable the CDC_AMC module in `make menuconfig` etc. Look up tutorials on how to compile a Linux kernel if you haven't done this before.

Comment: what doe you mean with where does It come form? it says on the Parrot website that it runs Linux 2.6.32.

Comment: Did it come with pre-installed software? Or did you download and install it? Where is this Parrot website, and does it have instructions on where to get the source?

Comment: it came with pre installed software and some other might already have tinkerd with it at the university. i have seen that it does accept FTDI based hardware as COM-ports so i will focus on that for now. i just need it to communicate so i can move on with my project. I want to thank you anyway for thinking with me. The driver i was looking for didn't even seem to exist yet.